# Passing text view value from adapter class to an activity class

Tags: android

I build a list view of person names and trying to show the name on different screen when that particular name is clicked on list view. I am implementing onClickListener method in adapter class. The problem is its not the value of text view but some id is shown on new screen. 
Here is my code. Thanks

```
holder.name.setText(friendName);

holder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);              

    intent.putExtra("NAME", holder.name.toString());

    context.startActivity(intent);

   }
});
```

on next the results becomes like that

[image]

Comment: show us where You get the string from Your intent please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only print the id of the TextView not the text of it

**solution:**

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", holder.name.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", holder.name.toString());
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", holder.name.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code add `getText()`:

```
intent.putExtra("NAME", holder.name.getText().toString());
```